# Information Extraction from Receipts and Predict Textual Zone

Tags: python, json, graph, conv-neural-network

I need to extract Information from Receipts with **Graph Convolutional Networks** and predict each textual zone correspond to what (TVA, price...).
But, I need a **Graph Modeler** to illustrate the text.

Could you hepl me please?

as input, I have json files (I have also xml file) which describe annotation of the text from images.
I tried this code :

```
def run_graph_modeler(normalized_dir, target_dir):
  print("Running graph modeler")

  img_files, word_files, _ = \
  get_normalized_filepaths(normalized_dir)

  for img_file, word_file in zip(img_files, word_files):
      # reads normalized data for one image
      img, word_areas, _ = load_normalized_example(img_file, word_file)

      # computes graph adj matrix for one image
      lines = line_formation(word_areas)
      width, height = cv_size(img)
      graph = graph_modeling(lines, word_areas, width, height)
      adj_matrix = form_adjacency_matrix(graph)

      # saves node features and graph
      save_graph(target_dir, img_file, graph, adj_matrix)
```